# Can not deploy juju charm

Tags: juju

Hello i get the following message

> Status Info: hook failed: "shared-db-relation-changed"

I get it on Glance,Cinder and Quantum. What does it mean?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It means that the hook script which handles the shared-db relation exited with an error.

Note that from version 2.0, Juju will automatically retry the hooks periodically.

You will find details about hook errors and how to debug them here:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/developer-debugging

Comment: In particular, try running `juju debug-log` in a separate terminal; then run `juju resolved --retry glance/0` and watch the output in the other terminal. That should be the easiest way to see what's actually happening in the failed hook.

Answer (score 1):

Try juju resolved "unit"

e.g. juju resolved glance/0

Comment: For a moment it gets green but after that again the same error

Comment: FWIW, `juju resolved` means "I am an expert in this service, so I logged in and fixed everything". Running it without having done so is basically never a good idea. However, running `juju resolved --retry` should be safe for anyone; it might not fix it, but it shouldn't make anything any *more* broken than it is already.